# Angular7 - view doesnt get updated when using debouncer

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this search service:

```
export class SearchbarComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Observable<any>;
  search = new FormControl();

  constructor(private searchService: SearchbarService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.search.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(1),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
      )
      .pipe(switchMap(search => 
       this.searchService.getSearchResults(search)));
  }
}
```

In the view I do something like this

```
<input placeholder="Search users here" [formControl]="search" />

<div *ngFor="let d of (data | async)" >
 {{ d.name }}
</div>
```

it works great but only on the first time but after showing the first result, the view doesnt get updated after that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't be `this.data = this.search.valueChanges`  instead of `this.users = this.search.valueChanges`?

Comment: Yes sorry that should be data. I will update my question. Though the main problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

Try this

#### .html

```
<input placeholder="Search users here" (keyup)="searchTerm$.next($event.target.value)"/>
```

#### .ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';


export class SearchbarComponent implements OnInit{

  searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>(); // <==== new

  constructor(private searchService: SearchbarService) {}

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.searchTerm$.subscribe( term => {
      this.searchService.getSearchResults(q)
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: Hmm this doesn't do anything. The service is not getting called at all

Comment: @GeorgeC. Nope, still same issue :/

Comment: @GeorgeC. I created a stackblitz. Check it out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zn9qeu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

I have create a working example base in your code the only difference between yours and mine is the service check mine

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchbarService {

  constructor() { }

  public getSearchResults(value) {
    const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    return of([...arr.map(c=> Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))]); // return an observable
  }

}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hlmwek)